# How to show $g^{-1}\circ f:\partial N\longrightarrow \partial N$ extends to a diffeomorphism $h:N\longrightarrow N$?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be two manifolds with boundary and let $$f, g:\partial N\longrightarrow \partial M,$$ two isotopic diffeomorphisms, that is, there exists a diffeomorphism $$F:\partial N\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow \partial M$$ such that $$F(x, 0)=f(x)\quad \textrm{and}\quad F(x, 1)=g(x).$$ It is easy to show $g^{-1}\circ f:\partial N\longrightarrow \partial N$ is isotopic to $id_{\partial N}$ for it suffices considering the isotopy $$H(x, t)=(g^{-1}\circ F)(x, t).$$ How can I show $g^{-1}\circ f$ extends to a diffeomorphism $h:N\longrightarrow N$?

**Obs:** Maybe the collar theorem will be useful. That theorem asserts there exists a diffeomorphism $$\alpha:\partial N\times [0, 1)\longrightarrow N,$$ such that $\alpha|_{\partial N\times \{0\}}=id_{\partial N}$.

Comment: $F$ won't be a diffeomorphism, do you mean *isotopy*?

Comment: My teacher calls $F$ a pseudoisotopy and he supposes it is a diffeomorphism..

Comment: The collar theorem is very useful.  What you need to know ahead of time is that the isotopy $H$ can be taken to be smooth as a map from $\partial N\times [0,1]$ to $\partial N$ and that $H(x,t) = x$ for $t \geq \frac{1}{2}$.  Then, define $h$ on the collar via the isotopy, and the identity elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @JasonDeVito , I'll think about it =)

Comment: Your observation is confounding. There's a diffeomorphism (this is the collar) from $\partial N\times [0,1)$ to a *neighborhood* of $\partial N$ in $N$. Your diffeomorphism $\alpha$ certainly doesn't map *onto* $N$.